# How to create var javascript via php?

Tags: javascript, php

How to create var javascript via php ?

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$get_data = mysqli_query($db_mysqli,"SELECT * FROM bad_word");
while($resilt_row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data))
{ 
    $bad_words = $bad_words."".$resilt_row [word].",";
}
//echo $bad_words;
?>

<script>
var bad_words = ["<?PHP echo $bad_words; ?>"];
alert(bad_words);
</script>
```

I want to get var javascript like this `var bad_words = ["fuck", "ass"];`
When alert it's get only blank result.

How can i do that ?

Comment: first of all, instantiate the `$bad_words` variable before the `while` block

Comment: Surely `$resilt_row [word]` should be `$resilt_row['word']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

include("connect.php");
$query = mysqli_query($db_mysqli,"SELECT * FROM bad_word");
$badWords = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{ 
    $badWords[] = $row['word'];
}
```

js

```
<script>
var bad_words = <?= json_encode($badWords); ?>;
alert(bad_words[0]);
console.log(bad_words);
</script>
```

I don't like gluing the strings if it's an array then pass it as an array with [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) function. Also in views it's better to use short syntax with `<?= ?>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$get_data = mysqli_query($db_mysqli,"SELECT * FROM bad_word");
while($resilt_row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data))
{ 
 $bad_words[] = $resilt_row['word'];
}
//echo $bad_words;
?>

<script>
var bad_words = ["<?php print implode('","',$bad_words); ?>"];
alert(bad_words);
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean: `implode` ?

Comment: Yes, mean implode :)

Comment: i get var bad_words = [""]; not var bad_words = ["fuck", "ass"]; ?

Comment: @weduti sepoyuei Sorry, just add an `echo`

Comment: @weduti sepoyuei But only as note: Did you now how many way exists to write something like F**k? It wil be an heavy task to prevent all bad words. And also showing the blockwords in the HTML code will help little crack-heads to get around your blocklist. Lets say i type: `F.uck` or `F!uck` .... neverending....

Answer (score 0):

If you want alert them as a string you can do it like this:

```
<script>
    var bad_words = ["<?php echo implode('","',$bad_words); ?>"];
    alert(bad_words);
</script>
```

Otherwise, you can print them as an array:

```
<script>
    var bad_words = <?php echo json_encode($bad_words) ?>;
    console.log(bad_words);
</script>
```

Comment: Only for the case  that you got the answer-check. This part is not ok `','` it must be `'","'`

Answer (score 0):

The string you're making is not the one you want.
You're not adding quotes.

Do this instead, using an array is better:

```
$get_data = mysqli_query($db_mysqli,"SELECT * FROM bad_word");
$bad_words = array();
while($resilt_row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data))
{ 
    $bad_words[] = "'" . $resilt_row[word]. "'";
}
```

And then, down in your js:

```
var bad_words = ["<?php echo implode(",", $bad_words) ?>"];
```

or (for short)

```
var bad_words = ["<?= implode(",", $bad_words) ?>"];
```

Comment: i get `var bad_words = ["fuck,ass"];` not `var bad_words = ["fuck", "ass"];` ?

Comment: Weird, you should have been getting `var bad_words = ['first', 'second']`